# Border spanning wider than its contents after 710px is reached

Tags: html, css, border

As the title says my border of `.border` div is spanning wider than what's inside it. It only happens once 710px is reached so you will need to expand the result window in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag8fou3n/).

I would like the border to remain around its contents without exceeding it.

Tia.

```
.border {  
  border: 1px solid #006699;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:8px;
border-top-left-radius:8px;}

.m1, .m2, .m3, .m4, .m5, .m6
{background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/mobile-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:56px;     overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}


.m1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.m2 {background-position: 0px -58px;}
.m3 {background-position: 0px -116px;}
.m4 {background-position: 0px -174px;}
.m5 {background-position: 0px -232px;}
.m6 {background-position: 0px -290px;}

.d1, .d2, .d3, .d4, .d5, .d6
{background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/desktop-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:56px;     overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}


.d1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.d2 {background-position: 0px -58px;}
.d3 {background-position: 0px -122px;}
.d4 {background-position: 0px -180px;}
.d5 {background-position: 0px -238px;}
.d6 {background-position: 0px -296px;}


.tabs__item.fill > img {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4
{background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/dock-cat-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:50px;
height:50px;     
    display:inline-block;
}



.c1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.c2 {background-position: 0px -52px;}
.c3 {background-position: 0px -104px;}
.c4 {background-position: 0px -156px;}
.c5 {background-position: 0px -208px;}


.c5{
background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/dock-cat-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;

width:100%; 
height:50px;

}

.container-dock {
  padding: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

.cats {
    width: 100%;
  height: auto;}


    .top_grow11{

    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }

.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}






@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .tabs--lg {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__content {
    border-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0A3D5D;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list {
    background: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

@media (max-width: 1070px) {
  .tabs--xl {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__content {
    border-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

.tabs__list {

margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;

background: #0A3D5D;

display: flex; /* Added */
}

/*
.tabs__list {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}*/


.tabs__item {
padding-left:1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

/*
.tabs__item {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}*/

.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
  border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  background: #0A3D5D;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #333333;

}
.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
  color: #262626;
}

.tabs__link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333333;
  padding: .0em 0em;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}
.tabs__link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tabs__area {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
          transition: opacity .5s linear;
  height: 0;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

.tabs__area--active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
          transition: opacity .5s linear;
  height: auto;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

.tabs__content {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #0A3D5D;
  border: 0px solid #0A3D5D;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  padding: 0.0rem;

}

<div class="border">
<div class="container-dock">
    <!-- This example will switch at a 760px width breakpoint -->
    <div class="tabs tabs--md">
        <ul class="tabs__list list-unstyled">
            <li class="tabs__item  tabs__item--active">
                                <a href="#tab-1" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c1"></a> </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-3" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c2"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-2" class="tabs__link"><img class="c3"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-4" class="tabs__link"><img class="c4"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item fill">
                <img class="c5">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs__content">
            <div id="tab-1" class="tabs__area tabs__area--active">

                      <div class="top_grow11">  
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/hd-wii-wallpapers-mario-kart-super-mario-galaxy-2.htm">
                <img class="d1"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/free-music-wallpaper-big-music-wallpapers.htm">
                <img class="d2"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/awesome-minecraft-hd-desktop-wallpapers-1080p-backgrounds-1920x1080.htm">
                <img class="d3"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="scooby-doo-wallpapers-character-backgrounds-coloring-pages-the-gang.htm">
                <img class="d4"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="free-hd-neon-colours-desktop-wallpapers-download.htm">
                <img class="d5"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

  <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="cool-hd-desktop-wallpapers-1920x1080.htm">
                <img class="d6"></img>              
                </a></div></div>
            <div id="tab-2" class="tabs__area">
                                  <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="facebook-timeline-covers-photos-851x315.htm">
                <img class="cats" src="thumbs/fb-cover_small.jpg"></img>                
                </a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-3" class="tabs__area"><div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="hd-minecraft-mobile-phone-wallpapers-1080x1920-steve-creeper.htm">

<img class="m1"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="hd-disney-frozen-wallpapers-for-mobile-phones-1080x1920.htm">

<img class="m2"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time-mobile-phone-wallpapers.htm">

<img class="m3"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="hd-super-mario-bros-world-mobile-phone-wallpapers-1080x1920.htm">

<img class="m4"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="lg-g2-g3-htc-one-max-s-m8-mobile-phone-wallpapers.htm">

<img class="m5"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="android-hd-mobile-phone-wallpapers-1080x1920.htm">

<img class="m6"></img></a>
        </div></div><div id="tab-4" class="tabs__area">
              <div class="top_grow11"><a href="twitter-headers-and-background-covers-1500x500.htm">  
<img class="cats" src="thumbs/caterpillar.png"></a>
            </div></div>
            <div id="tab-5" class="tabs__area">

            </div>
            <div id="tab-6" class="tabs__area">

            </div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.container-dock` has a max-width of 700px whereas `.border` is 100% (`display:block` with no width means it will stretch to 100%), remove the max width from `.container-dock` to make it fill `.border` or add a max width to `.border`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag8fou3n/1/)

I also added `overflow:hidden` to `.border` so the rounded corners stay round

Comment: I cant believe i didn't see that. Thanks and the rounded corners are great too.

Comment: hahaha, coding blindness - I often get that when I stare at the same code for hours!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the `<div>` with the class of `.container-dock` set to a width of 100% with it's contents having a fixed width. So the container is stretching the full width of the page and the contents aren't. Place the border on the contents or change the width property of the container!